# VS 2008 Database Project - During Deploy 'DatabaseName' undefined

Tags: database, deployment, database-project

I am using VS 2008 and have inhertied a database project that I am trying to deploy.  The deploy I am doing is to a new database. (as if I were setting up a new installation)

The Deploy Action is: Create Scrip and deploy to Database.

I get the following error: Schema.dbschema(0,0)Error TSD01268: SQL Execution error: A fatal error occurred. The variable DatabaseName could not be found.

The DatabaseName is defined in the project properties.

If I look a the deployment script I see the declaration is commented out.  I can remove the comment and run the script manualy and it works,  but when I regenerate the script the declaration is commented out again.

```
/*
:setvar DatabaseName "TestDb"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
*/
GO
```

I have searched for a setting that would cause the declaration to be commented out, but haven't found anything.

I want to be able to run the deployment script without editing it everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

In Database.sqldeployment there is an option under Advanced Options called "CommentOutSetVarDeclarations".

Comment: I so appreciate you. Productions deploy was threatened)

Comment: I am unable to find Database.sqldeployment? I am trying to deploy my database project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified in the project settings that you wish to always re-create the database when deploying? IF not, try setting this option to see if that resolves this for you. [See this MSDN article for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272681%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#bkmk_build_events).

Comment: I changed the setting to alway re-create the database when deploying, but it had no effect.  Thanks for point out that setting to me, however, I will be useful.

Comment: Found it!  Thanks TIm for pointing me to the right place.

In Database.sqldeployment there is an option under Advanced Options called "CommentOutSetVarDeclarations".